# Is it advisable to have 2 web modules in a single IntelliJ project?

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

I created an IntelliJ (9) project, and it started off as a single maven pom.xml project.

This project is a spring mvc web application.

I now realize it will be better to actually have 2 spring mvc applications.

Since I use maven now to build and run the application (using the jetty plugin), should I create the 2nd spring mvc application in the same project?

If so, I guess I have to re-work the folders so it is like:

```
myapp-models/
myapp-spring1/
myapp-spring2/
```

So this way each spring app will have:

```
/src/java/main/webapp (or whatever it is, I used a simple web arch type)
```

Does this make sense?

Do I even bother setting things up in IntelliJ to build using the IDE? (using modules I think?)

Can I still build and run using intelliJ?

BTW, when browsing folders in IntelliJ, it is annoying to keep clicking through the first 3 folders since they are empty, is there a faster way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This setup is just fine. You may choose which artifacts you want to deploy on Jetty. myapp-spring1 or myapp-spring2 or both. (Maybe artifacts were introduced after IntelliJ IDEA 9.)

BTW: I usually use "View as Package" in the Project tab. There you can select "Compact empty middle packages". At least in IntelliJ 10/11, but Im sure there is something similar in version 9.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in using multiple modules in Intellij.  I create multi module projects all the time.